# Multiple Array input in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I Want to get multiple arrays, For example :

a(number of arrays)

Suppose let's say a=3

```
arr1[1,4,8,9....n]
arr2[2,4,9.....n]
arr3[2,6...n]
```

The values should be user inputs.

The issue here is the array will be repeated and the last value entered will be stored only..

Code so far:

```
def main():
    a=input("Enter the number of array's: ")
    k=1
    for _ in range(a):
        array = list(map(int, input("Enter %s'st array"%k).split())) 
    print(array)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: Please edit your post, as opposed to adding code in the comments

Comment: You can solve the issue in your code using a list of lists instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():
    a=int(input("Enter the number of array's: "))
    size=int(input("Each array size: "))
    arrays=dict()
    for i in range(1, a+1):
        # arrays['array_'+str(i)]=[ j for j in range(1, size) lamda x: ]
        arrays['array_'+str(i)] = list(map(lambda j: int(input('value: ')), [ j for j in range(size)] ))

    print(arrays)
```

## Hope this will help you

Comment: can you please explain arrays=dict()?

Comment: dict is a build-in class I have created the empty dict object with reference arrays, instead of doing,
arrays = {}

Comment: instead of dict can we use list?

Comment: {'array_1': [1], 'array_2': [2], 'array_3': [3]}
how to get a specific output let . say i want values of 'array_3'???

Comment: Yes, you can use list. Then your output will look like,
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

for that:
my_array_list = list()
for i in range(1, a+1): 
my_array_list.append(list(map(lambda j: int(input('value: ')), [ j for j in range(size)] )))

Comment: how to get the values of the array example:  {'array_1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'array_2': [3, 4, 5, 6], 'array_3': [7, 8, 9, 0]}

Comment: By iterating the dict,
arrays =  {'array_1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'array_2': [3, 4, 5, 6], 'array_3': [7, 8, 9, 0]}
for k, v in arrays.items():
    # here k will be array_1  
    # and v will be value of key array_1 i.e [1, 2, 3, 4]
    # and so on

but make sure dict is unordered collection.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is this part:

```
for _ in range(a):
    array = list(map(int, input("Enter %s'st array"%k).split()))
```

Every time you assign to `array` you overwrite the previous value that you stored. In order to keep all the arrays you create, you'll have to keep them in a separate list. Try something like this:

```
arrays = list()
for i in range(int(a)):
    arrays.append(list(map(int, input("Enter %s'st array" % (i + 1)).split())))

for array in arrays:
    print(array)
```

EDIT: You also weren't incrementing `k`, which means "Enter 1'st array" would come up for every prompt. Since you are in a loop anyway, you can use the loop variable (I have added this in as `i`) as the number in this prompt. You have to add 1 so that it starts at 1 and goes up, rather than starting at 0. Thanks for spotting that @accdias.

Also, you need to pass an integer to range(), and when you get input from the command line it will come in as a string. So, just call int() on it before passing it to range. I have edited the code above to reflect this.

Comment: I guess that ```%k``` on input should be ```% a + 1``` instead, right?

Comment: def main():
  arrays = list()
  a = int(input("Enter number of arrays: "))
  k = 0
for _ in range(a):
    arrays.append(list(map(int, input("Enter %s'st array"%k).split())))

for array in arrays:
    print(array)

Comment: for _ in range(a):
NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: Have edited the code and added another note to the post as I noticed another bug.